# pls give the solution . this query will not work

Tags: postgresql

```
select * 
from masters."RCM" 
where id in (select rcm_id 
             from masters."TASK" 
             where id in (select audit_details->>'task_id' 
                          from masters."AUDIT" 
                          where id=43))
```

apply after this code some error will occured.

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint = text
> LINE 5:              where id in (select audit_details->>'task_id' 
>                               ^
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
> SQL state: 42883
> Character: 115
> ```

Comment: Please have a look at: [Help my write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifies. They are much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it.

Comment: Re-write your query to a join form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"TASK".id` is a bigint value, but `audit_details->>'task_id'` returns a text (varchar) value. Postgres prevents you from comparing apples to oranges, so you can't compare those two things directly.

As the error message suggests you need to add an [explicit type cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS).

```
...
where id in (select (audit_details->>'task_id')::bigint
             from ...)
```

Comment: Casting to BIGINT may cause an error (for example, `task_id`'s values may be '5', '5-1', '5-1a', ...). Maybe `id::text` will be more safe?

Comment: @Akina: how do you know that the task_ids have such strange values in them if they are supposed to be compared with a bigint?

Comment: For example, masters.task is integral data and contains tasks only whereas masters.audit stores tasks, subtasks, task stages, etc... moreover, I have seen real application with those structure (not on Postgress, MS Access).